# Нужны ли ещё где-нибудь кавычки в следующем афоризме?

Tags: орфография

Если человеку, в какой-нибудь интернет-дискуссии, слегка показалось, что его сильно, незаслуженно, оскорбили, приравняв к тем, кто это оскорбление заслужил, то он, по всей вероятности, избавляясь «от такого» чувства обиды, выведет на орбиту происходящего мысль, подобную навигационному спутнику.

Comment: Может и от такого не надо выделять кавычками?

Comment: Может и афоризма "не надо"? Ну есть некое уподобление, афоризм-то где? Кавычки, разуметтся, не нужны. Никакие.

Comment: Пусть не афоризм, высказывание, изречение. Афоризм - краткое выразительное изречение. Спорно что кратко, что выразительно!

Comment: Так простите, у вас-то ни краткости, ни выразительности. Афоризму еще требуется некоторое обобщение. Его тоже нету.

Comment: Смотря с чем сравнить. Спорить не буду. С Вами, в принципе, согласен.

Answer (score 1):

Слегка показалось, что сильно оскорбили? Вот он, афоризм-то. )))

Предложение необходимо облегчить, во-первых, убрав слегкапоказанность и оскорблениеприравненность, во-вторых, сняв кучку запятых, об которые глаз спотыкается, в-третьх, от какого "от такого"? - ни в кавычках, ни без это лишнее (не было указано, какое именно чувство обиды):

*Если человеку в какой-нибудь интернет-дискуссии показалось, что его сильно и незаслуженно оскорбили, то он, по всей вероятности, избавляясь от чувства обиды, выведет на орбиту происходящего мысль, подобную навигационному спутнику.*

Мысль, подобная навигационному спутнику (не путать с другим каким) на орбите происходящего, - тоже круто! Не афоризм ещё, но уже метафора.

Отдельно надо подумать над запятой после "вероятности":

*...то он, по всей вероятности, избавляясь от чувства обиды,* -

может, вводное всё-таки относится к деепричастному обороту?

И большие сомнения вызывает запятая перед "подобная" - впереди нет слова, которое эта подобность могла бы уточнять...

Смотрите, как на равных проходят варианты у Толстого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Растянянутое предложение получилось от того, что пытался передать в нём правду как можно больше. И даже в моём виде «по всей вероятности» правильнее(правдивее) было бы заменить на «может быть».

Comment: Денис, длинноты затуманивают смысл. Если дорого каждое слово и не хочется расставаться, пассаж нужно разрубить на короткие предложения.